# ¿Como Ordenar Vectores en C#?

Tags: c#, array

Como puedo hacer que mi vector se ordene de menor a mayor, lo que pasa es que ya tengo mi método que debería de realizar eso, solo que tengo un problema de lógica, ya que me marca error al momento de realizar mi if

```
 public void ordeanar()
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < vector.Length; x++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < vector.Length - x;k++ )
                {

                    if (vector[k] < vector[k + 1]) --> ERROR
                    {
                        int aux;
                        aux = vector[k];
                        vector[k] = vector[k + 1];
                        vector[k + 1] = aux;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al parecer se trata del algoritmo de la burbuja. Si es así, entonces lo correcto sería:

```c#
public void ordeanar()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < vector.Length-1; x++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < vector.Length-1 - x;k++ )
            {

                if (vector[k] < vector[k + 1])
                {
                    int aux;
                    aux = vector[k];
                    vector[k] = vector[k + 1];
                    vector[k + 1] = aux;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Se le resta uno a la longitud total del vector para que no dé error cuando se pida `vector[k+1]`, estando en la última iteración, en donde `k` debería ser igual a `vector.length - 2`

Answer (score 4):

Por que no usar las bondades de Linq? Salvo que estés estudiando algoritmos, no es necesario ni recomendable implementar estas funciones manualmente.

Esta forma genera un Segundo array con los datos ordenados.

```
var ordenado = vector.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
```

Esta forma ordena el array existente

```
Array.Sort(vector);
```

Si quieres trabajar de forma descendente.

```
var ordenado = vector.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToArray();
```

Ordenar el mismo array de forma descendente

```
Array.Sort(vector, delegate(int a, int b) { return b - a; });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i < maxNumbers; i++)
    { //Con este ciclo (for) obtenemos el primer numero del arreglo numbers
        for (j = 0; j < maxNumbers; j++)
        {// Con este ciclo (for) obtenemos el segundo numero del arreglo numbers
            if (numbers[i] > numbers[j]) {
                /*
                Ejemplo visual del proceso (Ordenar de MAYOR a MENOR):
                Array ejemplo: {1,2,3,4,5,6}
                Obtenemos el valor de posicion i (i, en primera instancia, es igual a 0): 1
                Obtenemos el valor de posicion j (j, en primera instancia, es igual a 1): 2
                Comparamos posicion i < j (1 < 2)
                    Si es cierta:
                        Guardamos posicion i (1) en variable temporal (number)
                        Ponemos valor de posicion j en posicion i (el array quedaria {2,2,3,4,5,6})
                        Ponemos valor number (1) en posicion j (el array quedaria {2,1,3,4,5,6})
                    Si es falsa
                        No se procede ninguna modificacion
                */
                number = numbers[i];
                numbers[i] = numbers[j];
                numbers[j] = number;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Muy buenas @Carlos Duri. Gracias por tu aportación, pero te indico que es una pregunta antigua. Por otra parte, viendo que eres nuevo en SOes te invito a que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla. Muchas gracias y esperemos seguir viéndote por aquí. Un saludo